# Leer fichero .txt e introducir datos leidos en variables

Tags: c, archivo

Tenía una duda acerca de como leer un fichero de texto en el que vienen los datos uno en cada linea e introducirlos en las variables que yo quiera.

Me explico:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char fichero[100], nombre[100], apellido[100];
int edad;


FILE *f;

printf("\n\nIntroduce el fichero desde donde quieras importar los datos: ");
fflush(stdin);
gets(fichero); //Introduzco Manualmente el nombre del fichero


f = fopen(fichero, "r"); //Abro el fichero en modo lectura 
                         **//****ES UN ARCHIVO .TXT******
if(f == NULL)    //Compruebo que se ha abierto correctamente
{
  printf("Error.No se ha podido abrir el fichero");
  exit(1);
}
fgets(nombre, 100, f);  //Utilizo la funcion fgets para coger cadena de
fscanf(f, "%d", &edad);  //caracteres y fscanf para tomar numeros y los 
fgets(apellido, 100, f); //guardo en las variables anteriormente creadas

printf("\n\nDATOS");   //Muestro esas variables por pantalla
printf("\n=======");
printf("\n\nNombre: %s",nombre);
printf("\nEdad: %i",edad);
printf("\nApellido: %s",apellido);
printf("\n\n\nPulse <intro> para finalizar...");
system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Como veis lo unico que intento hacer es abrir el fichero y copiar los datos pero no soy capaz de que los guarde. El contenido que tiene el archivo .txt del que esta tomando los datos es el siguiente:

```
Luis Miguel
28
Perez Hernandez
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿ No podrías pegar los mensajes ( *warning*s o *error*s ) que te da el compilador, si es que te da alguno ? Para completar la pregunta. Ah, y te he añadido el `#include <stdio.h>`, que se ha perdido en el *copy/paste*. +1 por la pregunta.

Comment: Que va, no da ningun error el compilador, funciona todo correctamente el fallo esta en que a la hora de mostrar las variables por pantalla no aparecen bien los datos es decir, que los estoy introduciendo mal en las variables fijo pero no se como hacer para solucionar eso

Comment: Jeje ... no da ningún *warning* **ahora** que la has editado :-) Tranquilo, que seguro te la responden en breve. Está **mucho** *mas mejor* formulada que las anteriores ;-)

Comment: Considera que, si tus preguntas anteriores no crees que vayan a ser *útiles/respondidas*, deberías de *borrarlas*. Para mantener esto *limpito*. Espero verte mas por aquí. Un saludo :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fscanf(f, "%d", edad);
```

Para que `fscanf` pueda modificar el contenido de `edad` es necesario que o bien dicha variable sea un puntero o bien le facilites una referencia a dicha variable. Lo correcto sería:

```
fscanf(f, "%d", &edad);
//              ^
```

Con eso ya te compilaría, ahora bien:

`fflush` está pensado para ser usado únicamente con buffers **de salida**. Usarlo con buffers de entrada es algo desaconsejado porque no lo contempla el estándar, luego el resultado puede variar entre compiladores y máquinas. Esto quiere decir que la siguiente línea sobra:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Si realmente necesitas limpiar el buffer de entrada tendrás que recurrir a otros artificios siempre y cuando sean conformes al estándar.

Otro detalle es que si `fgets` se encuentra con un salto de línea lo incluye a la cadena de lectura y no creo que sea lo que pretendes. El resultado es que la consola te mostrará algo así:

```
Luis Miguel
                 <-- Salto de linea
28
```

Aquí se aprecia tambíen otro error. ¿Dónde está el apellido? El problema aquí es que `scanf` **no descarta** el salto de línea, por lo que la lectura del apellido acaba leyendo únicamente el salto de línea.

Para corregir estos problemas de lectura puedes usar algo tal que:

```
fgets(nombre, 100, f);
fscanf(f, "%d\n", &edad);      // lees la edad y descartas el salto de linea
fgets(apellido, 100, f);

nombre[strlen(nombre)-1] = 0;     // Elimina el salto de linea
apellido[strlen(apellido)-1] = 0; // Elimina el salto de linea
```

**Nota** tu primera versión no pasaba `edad` como referencia a la función `fscanf`

Comment: Muchas gracias ya he conseguido solucionarlo y gracias a esa ultima parte, eliminar el salto de linea. Todo correcto al 100% Muchas gracias